# how do I build a static shared library(self-sustain) using musl?

Tags: c, linux, alpine-linux, musl

For some reasons, I want to build a `static` shared library: a self sustain
library that without any external dependent library.

My build environment is alpine linux.
(I believe that gcc is /usr/bin/aarch64-alpine-linux-musl-gcc)

I build my shared library as follows:

```
gcc -fpic -c jpg_to_bmp.c -o jpg_to_bmp.o
ld -fpic -shared -static -lc -lstdc++ jpg_to_bmp.o FreeImage/Dist/libfreeimage.a -o libmy_img_static.so
gcc -I ./ -L ./ main.c -o main.o
```

However

```
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=`pwd` ./main test.jpg test.bmp
```

dies with Segmentation fault

if I link the shared library without `-static -lc -lstdc++`

```
ld -fpic -shared -static -lc -lstdc++ jpg_to_bmp.o FreeImage/Dist/libfreeimage.a -o libmy_img_static.so
```

Everything works fine.

How do I build a static shared library(self-sustain) using musl ?
Did I miss any step or flag ?

Comment: Why link `stdc++`?

Comment: @kiner_shah  because libfreeimage.a is a c++ library